# knowing the value ldi command is placing in X, Y, Z-Register

Tags: pointers, assembly, avr

How can you know what value the different registers get when I am running the program? like we see in **picture 1**, after line 8 the R30 register(Z-Pointer) is changed to 0x94 and if I run one more line R29 become 0x01. but R28 and R31 have no value change.

```
.cseg           
.org 0
rjmp start
.org 0x46

start: 
 ldi r31,high(tabell*2)         
 ldi r30, low(tabell*2)     //line 8    
 ldi r29,high(behandlet)            
 ldi r28,low(behandlet)         

tabell:
 .db 0xc2,0x09,0x64,0xab
 .db 0x73, 0x01, 0x0c, 0xfb

 .dseg
 .org 0x100
behandlet:
 .byte 8
```

**Picture 1:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are confused about. Just figure out the address of the symbols involved, and apply the given operations. Finally place the result into the given destination register.

Line 8: `ldi r30, low(tabell*2)` Okay, so we need to figure out the address of `tabell`.  Since `start` is at `0x46` and this is program memory, each instruction counts as 1. Thus, `tabell` is at `0x4A`. Multiplying by 2 gives us `0x94`, and taking the low byte is a no-op obviously. So that's why `r30` changes to `0x94`.

Next line: `ldi r29,high(behandlet)` That's even simpler, since `behandlet` is directly after an `org 0x100`, so that is its address. Taking the high byte of that is obviously `0x01`.

`r28` and `r31` don't change, since they are already zero, and the respective instructions also load them with zero. See above for why `high(tabell*2)` and `low(behandlet)` are both `0`.